# How to check for the first element in an Array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have the following Array Loop set up. It simply loops through a string and checks to see if each item matches a letter and sets some variables accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IN="ItemName -a -b"

itemA=0
itemB=0
itemI=0

while IFS=' -' read -ra ARR; do
    for x in "${ARR[@]}"; do
        echo "x = $x"
        y=${x:0:1}
        echo "y = $y"
        case $y in
            "a") itemA=1 ;;
            "b") itemB=1 ;;
            "I") itemI=1 ;;
        esac
    done
done <<< "$IN"

echo "itemA is $itemA
echo "itemB is $itemB"
echo "itemI is $itemI"
```

However, for the first element ("itemName"), I need to set this separately, so that it isn't checked as part of the case stemement.
Ideally I want to end up with:

```
itemName is ItemName
itemA is 1
itemB is 1
itemI is 0
```

How can I check for the first element? I tried

```
if [ ${ARR[0]} ] ; then
    itemName=$x
else
 . . . 
fi
```

but ended up with none of the variables getting set.

Comment: Isn't itemI ItemName? just save x for itemI and return x instead of 0/1 for itemI if that's what you want.

Comment: This looks like a job for [getopts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts). Also see the [Small getopts tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).

Comment: cheers Dani_I, but if I have `ItemName -a -b -I` or `AnotherItem -a -b` then `ItemI` will be wrong. Is there simply a way of saying `if this is the first item in an Array do this else do that`?

Comment: maybe it's me, but `getopts` looks overly complex for my needs, Plus I couldn't get it to work, but cheers anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you're using a `while` loop. Loose the `while` and your problems disappear:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IN="ItemName -a -b"
itemA=0
itemB=0
itemI=0

## Read the array, no loop required
IFS=' -' read -ra ARR <<<"$IN"
## Save the 1st element as itemN
itemN=${ARR[0]}
## Remove itemN from the array
unset ARR[0]
## Now loop over the rest
for x in "${ARR[@]}"; do
    y=${x:0:1}
    case $y in
        "a") itemA=1 ;;
        "b") itemB=1 ;;
        "I") itemI=1 ;;
        esac
done

echo "itemN is $itemN"
echo "itemA is $itemA"
echo "itemB is $itemB"
echo "itemI is $itemI"
```

Running the script above prints:

```
itemN is ItemName
itemA is 1
itemB is 1
itemI is 0
```

Comment: You are quite right, that is exactly what I was after, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is necessarily the best way, but it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IN="ItemName -a -b"

itemName=0
itemA=0
itemB=0
itemI=0

while IFS=' -' read -ra ARR; do
    for x in "${ARR[@]:1:0}"; do
        itemName=$x
    done

    for x in "${ARR[@]:1}"; do
        y=${x:0:1}
        case $y in
            "a") itemA=1 ;;
            "b") itemB=1 ;;
            "I") itemI=1 ;;
        esac
    done
done <<< "$IN"

echo "itemName is $itemName"
echo "itemA is $itemA
echo "itemB is $itemB"
echo "itemI is $itemI"
```

Basically, I processed the Array twice. Once to get just the first Item, and then again to get all items except the first item.

Answer (score 0):

I would use more arrays. This answer relies on bash version 4 for associative arrays.

```
IFS=' -' read -ra words <<<"$IN"
declare -A items

for i in "${words[@]}"; do
    [[ $i == "ItemName" ]] && continue
    items["${i:0:1}"]=1
done

for key in "${!items[@]}"; do
    echo "item $key is ${items[$key]}"
done
```

```
item a is 1
item b is 1
```

If you need to set some default values for the items array:

```
declare -A items=([a]=0 [b]=0 [c]=0)
```

Then you would see

```
item a is 1
item b is 1
item c is 0
```